# How to send email from a secure network with closed SMTP port

Tags: c#, email, network-security

I tried to Send email from a Desktop app using SMTP sever but my network is secure and port is closed.

So, is there another way to send email like using Gmail api ?!

I use this code but doesn't work with me

```
  public void Send_Mail(string HTMLBody, string MailTo)
  {
      MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
      SmtpClient SmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

      string MailSubject = "Subject;
      string MailFrom = "from@xxxx.com";


      Mail.Subject = MailSubject;
      Mail.Body = HTMLBody;
      Mail.To.Add(MailTo);

      MailAddress From = new MailAddress(MailFrom);
      Mail.From = From;

      Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

      SmtpClient.Host = "host";
      SmtpClient.Port = port;
      SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
      SmtpClient.Send(Mail);            
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your secure network have an SMTP server to use?

Comment: to use it my machine must take a static IP and each machine will use this tool must take a static IP and it is not good.

Answer (score 2):

If your network doesn't allow outbound connections to whatever port gmail uses (or restricts a particular protocol, or IP, etc), then there's nothing you can do. You would have to talk to the "network guys" to either remove this restriction for you or better yet, ask them to provide the local smtp server for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked in a place where we had a similar problem. Desktop machines were not allowed to send emails, but servers could be permissioned to talk to an SMTP server.

What we ended up doing was writing a windows service that listened for messages placed on a queue (Tibco EMS in our case, but MSMQ would also do). The service took the messages from the queue and passed them onto the SMTP server is was permissioned to use.

It added an extra step, and process, to the system, but was enough to satisfy the compliance department.

Comment: I didn't deal with windows service before so i can't understand how it read from a queue and where will be this queue.

Comment: You'd need a middleware solution (Microsoft MSMQ, for example) in order to host the queue. The queue will then me available to your desktops and your servers.

Comment: Is every client has its Queue and all of them will contact to the server ?

Comment: No, the queue is managed by a MSMQ instance on a shared server. Desktop apps write to the queue, and your server process pulls off the queue. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing

Comment: Did you mean that the Queue will be on Server and my app and windows Service will be on my PC ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally a "secure network" means that there is a firewall in place that restricts the traffic and only allows communication on certain ports like port 80 and maybe 8080.

Such networks (workplaces, shared office spaces, schools, eg.) usually have an outgoing SMTP server you could use. Alternatively you will need to use a server that can be contacted through the port(s) that are actually open or relay/tunneling the request through a third party.